# Firebase - fetching data, limited by date

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, firebase

I would like to ask, is it possible fetching only limited amount of data in specific/defined period of time e.g.

I want download only data which had been written since 20.01.2014 - 21.01.2014.
I have been using iOS framework to communicate with Firebase server.

Comment: What you mean by Local Database, all of data are available and visible at xxx.firebaseio.com I communicate by firebase framework observing changes in selected paths. Could you more clarify your question.

Comment: just chill buddy and be nice on stack overflow. My meaning is are you downloading and stored data in local sqlite3 database before display in to your application?

Comment: surely I am, If you think I was not, sorry for that.
I would like to use only recent data (let say this is only one value) without storing out of date. But sometimes I want fetch archival data that is why I asked.

Answer (score 1):

This is covered under the Firebase docs for [Ordered Data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ordered-data.html) and [Queries and Limits](https://www.firebase.com/docs/queries.html).

The steps are:

- use [setValue:andPriority](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios-api/Classes/Firebase.html#//api/name/setValue%3aandPriority%3a) instead of `setValue`
- set the priority to the date of the event/message
- use `queryStartingAtPriority` and `queryEndingAtPriority` to fetch a specific date range

Thus:

```
// Trigger event for messages between 7:32 PM and 8:11 PM on 2/11/2012
[[[messageListRef queryStartingAtPriority:@1329017600] queryEndingAtPriority:@1329019865] observeEventType:FEventTypeChildAdded withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) { ... }];
```